# ClassLoader.java:-2:in `load': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: in hbase

Tags: hbase

I am getting this exception when i start hbase shell. I am using hbase version 0.94.10
I am running this on a seperate server machine.

Caused by:
ClassLoader.java:-2:in `load': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jffi1844046871189117608.tmp: /tmp/jffi1844046871189117608.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

I tried to google about the same and found that this could be a problem because of the /tmp folder not being accessbile.
So i changed the path of the tmp directory in hbase-default.xml file and tried again. But still the same issue.

Could someone please help?

Comment: I had a similar issue on spark.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the `/tmp folder` in mounted using `noexec` option, remount it for fix the issue.

```
sudo mount -o remount exec /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question. I was actually trying to install Hbase in a new server and it turned out that there was no permission in that server. There are a few posts out in google which says that if the file could be created in the tmp folder, it means permission would be available for that user.

I went by this logic and it did not turn out to be right. SO even if you see some files being created in the tmp folder, please make sure to ensure that the permissions are available from your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command mentioned below to get rid of **"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: in HBase"** error while starting HBase Shell.

**mkdir -m 777 /tmp/hbase_java_io_tmp**

Comment: Can you explain what this achieves and why it works?

Comment: I don't know why it works but the issue was resolved by doing this. I also found it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said this issue is due to restrictions on /tmp folder. To solve this issue add java option
HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path_to_some_other_directory"
in hbase script. This will make hbase to use this new directory instead of /temp and will resolve the issue.